# Laravel + Vue/axios Api call to subdomain access-control-allow-origin

Tags: laravel, vue.js, header, cors, http-headers

I know there is a lot of information about this kind of stuff. But I do get a bit confused about a lot of things. First of all. If I have an **laravel API** on **api.example.com** and my **Vue project** on **www.example.com**

So from **www.example.com** I do an API call to **api.example.com**. So where should I handle this error? I already added the headers to my Axios config like so:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
};
```

After some reading I read you have to handle this server side. So I tried installing

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

but it gives me this:

> Command "optimize" is not defined.

So okee maybe there is something wrong with my composer or the library idk. But before I waste another couple of hours with this. I would like to ask a bit more information about what the applications are asking for and maybe even how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You've set the access controls in api client, where you have to put it inside the server means in laravel.

Your server will decide whom to serve. not your clients will decide weather they should use means VueJS.

add cors middleware in laravel

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

You'll good to go.

Comment: Create this middleware and then add this middle ware to all my routes?

Comment: @NielsLucas add to all the routes which you want to use as an api service.

Comment: @NielsLucas will tell you by testing. I haven't tested it yet. sorry